# Code Download file from Doc icon image in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, document-library

I have written  code  where it will show the Sharepoint document library in sp grid view.

In the grid view it will show the doc icon Image correctly. Now i want to Download the uploade document from this when clicked on Doc icon.

Here is the code and Out put of the Image

```
    SPGridView gv = new SPGridView();
                gv.ID = "gv";
                gv.EmptyDataText = "No items found!";
                gv.AllowSorting = true;
                gv.AllowFiltering = true;
                gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                gv.EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks = true;
                CreateBoundField("Type", "Type", false, gv);
                CreateBoundField("Title", "Title", false, gv);
                CreateBoundField("Date", "Date", false, gv);
                CreateBoundField("ProcessTask", "ProcessTask", false, gv);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPListItemCollection items = web.Lists["Shared Documents"].Items;            
                dt.Columns.Add("Type");
                dt.Columns.Add("Title");
                dt.Columns.Add("Date");
                dt.Columns.Add("ProcessTask");
                foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    string value = item["ProcessTask"].ToString();
                    value = value.Substring(value.LastIndexOf(";#") + 2);
                    string docicon = SPUtility.ConcatUrls("/_layouts/images",
                    SPUtility.MapToIcon(item.Web, SPUtility.ConcatUrls(item.Web.Url, item.Url), "", IconSize.Size16));
                    dr["Type"] = string.Format("<img src='{0}' />", docicon);
                    dr["Title"] = item.Title;
                    dr["Date"] = item["Created"].ToString().Split(' ')[0];
                    dr["ProcessTask"] = value;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                gv.DataSource = dt;
                gv.DataBind();
                this.Controls.Add(gv);
               SPListItemCollection _GridCollection = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Shared Documents"].Items;
                DataTable _MyDatabale = _GridCollection.GetDataTable();
                gvdetails.DataSource = _MyDatabale;
                gvdetails.DataBind();

}

private void CreateBoundField(string sDataField, string sHeaderText, bool bReadOnly, SPGridView theGridView)
    {
        BoundField field = new BoundField();
        field.DataField = sDataField;
        field.HeaderText = sHeaderText;
        field.HtmlEncode = false;
        field.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#808080");
        field.HeaderStyle.Font.Names = new string[] { "verdana", "arial", "helvetica", "sans-serif" };
        field.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
        if (sHeaderText.ToLower().Equals("type"))
        {
            field.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
            field.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(35);
            field.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(35);
        }
        field.ReadOnly = bReadOnly;
        if (!bReadOnly)
            field.SortExpression = sDataField;
        field.Visible = true;
        theGridView.Columns.Add(field);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but it's exceptionally hard to understand your objective. Are you asking how to add a hyper-link to the page you are rendering so that users can download the file or documnt associated with the gridview's row?

Comment: That is how I am reading it Robert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get hold of the SPFile object, which is a property of a ListItem item, and get the ServerRelativeUrl property. Add this to an `<a>` tag and you're done.

```
//the rest of your code omitted for brevity
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
    SPFile file = item.File;
    string relativeUrl = file.ServerRelativeUrl; //returns a string in the form /Site_Name/Subsite_Name/Folder_Name/File_Name

    //surround your img tag with an anchor tag
    dr["Type"] = string.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='{1}' /></a>", relativeUrl, docicon);
}
```

Comment: Wow Great i think i am close now .. Can we have a check box enable before the File As we get in OOB sharepoint document library ??

Comment: can we get through jquery